# вводное в середине присоединительной конструкции?

Tags: вводные-слова

На сайте

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/726-210_vvodnye_slova__slovosochetaniya_i_predlozheniya.html:

Но если в частности входит в состав присоединительной конструкции (в начале её или в конце), то оно выделяется занятыми вместе с этой конструкцией:

1.За эту работу охотно возьмутся многие, и в частности я;

2.За эту работу охотно возьмутся многие, и я в частности.

Но разве в первом предложении *в частности* стоит не в середине присоединительной конструкции?

И должно быть: За эту работу охотно возьмутся многие, и, в частности, я.

Или если рассматривать *многие* и *я* как однородные, то можно и так:

За эту работу охотно возьмутся многие и, в частности, я.

Comment: На сайте русского языка, пожалуйста, соблюдайте правила орфографии — начинайте предложение с заглавной буквы.

Answer (score 3):

За эту работу охотно возьмутся многие, **и в частности я.**

Здес И ― присоединительный союз, который тесно примыкает к вводному слову и не обособляется от него.

Примеры:

Руководители Союза писателей, **и в частности я**, несут ответственность за то, что Борщаговский был членом редколлегии «Нового мира», за то, что Холодов заведывал отделом «Литературной газеты». [К. М. Симонов. 1949]

Таков исходный пункт той критики, которой мы ― **и в частности я** в своей «Истории» ― подвергали их политическое поведение. [П. Н. Милюков. Воспоминания (1859—1917). Том второй (1940-1943)]